# When using Express Migration Tool to just migrate databases do I need to provide the Website folder path?

Tags: express-migration-tool

I am going to use Express Migration Tool 3.1 to migrate the databases from 7.2 -> 9.0.  I only need to migrate the databases, I don't need to migrate the files (I already have that part figured out separately).  Do I still need to provide the Express Migration Tool with the paths to the Source and Target website folder?

The reason I am asking ahead of time (instead of just trying it so see what happens) is I am doing this in a multi-server setup.  The source instance is on SERVER-A.  The target instance is on SERVER-B.  And the Express Migration Tool will be run on SERVER-B.  Do I have to go through the process of mapping a drive from SERVER-A to SERVER-B so that I have the path to the SERVER-A website folder even if I'm not migrating any files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you run the Express Migration Tool 3.1, you must decide whether you want to run it on the same computer as your source and target instances or on a different computer.

If you run the tool on a different computer, you must ensure that it has Server Message Block (SMB) access to the source, target, and comparison instance's database servers and file system, and then you can specify the network path to the file system on the source instance and the comparison instance.

You are using the tool where target instance are running on SERVER B, and the source instance is located on a remote server(SERVER A). You must ensure that the Core and Master databases are accessible and the connection strings are valid for the computer you are running the tool from.

```
<add name="Core" connectionString="Data Source=SOURCE SERVER;Initial Catalog=SERVER;Integrated Security=False;User ID=YOUR ID;Password=YOUR PASSWORD"/>
```

On the Instance parameter sub tab you must need to enter the source and target  website folder field path, enter the network path of your  source website folder . Be sure that using the path it can access the website folder .

[image]